# Mysql query inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Whats wrong with this query? It says: Syntax to use near '`INNER JOIN` `cm_competitions ON cm_matches.competition_id = cm_competitions.compet`
What's wrong In this?

```
$query_matches = "SELECT cm_matches.match_id, cm_competitions.name 
                   INNER JOIN cm_competitions.name 
                   ON cm_matches.competition_id = cm_competitions.competition_id 
                    FROM cm_matches 
                    WHERE cm_matches.club_h_id = 8 
                   OR cm_matches.club_v_id = 8";
```

Comment: Basicly the order - `SELECT col FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.col = tbl2.col` instead of `SELECT col INNER JOIN...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed `FROM cm_matches` after `INNER JOIN` which should be before `INNER JOIN`. So try this query:

```
SELECT cm_matches.match_id, cm_competitions.name 
  FROM cm_matches
 INNER JOIN cm_competitions 
    ON cm_matches.competition_id = cm_competitions.competition_id
 WHERE cm_matches.club_h_id = 8 
    OR cm_matches.club_v_id = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **INNER JOIN** after **FROM** tag:

```
$query_matches = "SELECT cm_matches.match_id, cm_competitions.name  
                  FROM cm_matches 
                  INNER JOIN cm_competitions 
                  ON cm_matches.competition_id = cm_competitions.competition_id
                  WHERE cm_matches.club_h_id = 8 
                  OR cm_matches.club_v_id = 8";
```

Comment: Thank you for illuminating me!

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
$query_matches = "SELECT cm_matches.match_id, cm_competitions.name FROM cm_matches INNER JOIN cm_competitions ON cm_matches.competition_id = cm_competitions.competition_id  WHERE cm_matches.club_h_id = 8 OR cm_matches.club_v_id = 8";
```

Answer (score -2):

Your query should be something like this:

```
$query_matches = "SELECT cm_matches.match_id, cm_competitions.name FROM cm_matches INNER JOIN cm_competitions ON cm_matches.competition_id = cm_competitions.competition_id WHERE cm_matches.club_h_id = 8 OR cm_matches.club_v_id = 8";
```

Comment: The question was not answered at the time i was submitting. And ya i missed the explanation. Thought it was self explanatory :)

Comment: It's basic syntax, since the author does not know it, it appears the documentation is not read. You could mention that the FROM clause is before the JOIN one and maybe link the offic documentation